# Wordpress show excerpt on homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was able to add code to be able to create an excerpt of a page on the twenty seventeen theme.  I was wondering how to put the excerpt on the homepage section instead of it being the entire pages information.  For example, the about page has 3 paragraphs of information, but I only want the 3 sentence excerpt to show on the homepage.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Page Excerpt" plugin.
or you can use "add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );" this, add in the function file.